# How to Make or Call sidebar in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I have such type of code in view, add.ctp file in Cake PHP.

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="content">
      ------------------
   </div>
   <div id="sidebar">
   ----------------
   </div>
</div>
```

Now in Layout, in default.ctp file, we access this code by this line.

```
<?php echo $this->fetch('content'); ?>
```

I have sidebar in each and every view file, and if I need some changes then I will go in each and every file and then change.

Now My Question is that, can I made a file in layout like sidebar.ctp or any thing else that I just call this file in my view. If I can, then how I will made such type of file.

Comment: did you take a look at [elements](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#elements)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it with include or elements like this

```
<?php echo $this->element('sidebar'); ?>
```

With the element, you make the **sidebar.ctp** file in the `View/Elements/` folder. 
Check for more information: [Cakephp 2 Elements](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#view-elements)

The other way is with include *(not my choice, but another way to accomplish it)*

```
<?php include('../View/Layouts/sidebar.ctp'); ?>
```

Comment: It was just an example how to use it, but thanks for the advise

Answer (score 2):

You can use elements and if the content in elements is dynamic you can use the blocks supported in latest version of cakephp.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html